Is there a way to submit a form with multiple copies of the same fields (or component) in an organized way?
I've got the following component:
<script>
    export let componentID;

    console.log("component iD", componentID)
</script>

<div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-6">
        <div class="sm:col-span-3">
            <label class="label">
                <span class="label-text text-lg">Title</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="track-title[][{componentID}]" class="input input-bordered input-lg w-full">
        </div>

        <div class="sm:col-span-1">
            <label class="label">
                <span class="label-text text-lg">Duration</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="track-duration[][{componentID}]" class="input input-bordered input-lg w-full">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

As you can see, this component contains only 2 input fields. I have the following route (+page.svelte) and what I want to do is to have multiple copies of the same component, something like this:
<script>
    import TrackForm from "../../components/forms/TrackForm.svelte";

</script>

<form method="POST">
    <TrackForm componentID="1" />

    <br/>
    <hr>
    <br/>
    <TrackForm componentID="2" />

    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-wide btn-info mt-10">Save</button>
</form>

Eventually, the components will be added dynamically using a button, for now, this is a proof of concept.
The action in +page.server.js is not doing anything at the moment, just printing the submitted data:
export const actions = {
    default: async ({ request }) => {
        const data = Object.fromEntries(await request.formData());
        console.log("data:", data);

        return {}
    }
}

When submitting the form I'm getting the following:
data: {
  'track-title[][1]': 'aaaaa',
  'track-duration[][1]': '111',
  'track-title[][2]': 'vbbb',
  'track-duration[][2]': '2222'
}

What I'm wondering is whether there's a way to automatically get the data in a better format, say:
[
   {
     "track-title": 'aaaaa',
     "track-duration": '111'
   },
   {
     "track-title": 'vbbb',
     "track-duration": '2222'
   }
]

or a library that does that.

SvelteKit has no built-in support for this. For more information, see How to receive array of object in Sveltekit Action?
So, you need to write your own solution to add support for it. The qs lib can parse what you want:
import qs from 'qs'

const body = `messages[0][title]=A&messages[0][content]=HelloA&messages[1][title]=B&messages[1][content]=HelloB'`

console.log(qs.parse(body))
/*
{
  messages: [
    { title: 'A', content: 'HelloA' },
    { title: 'B', content: "HelloB'" }
  ]
}
*/

In Sveltekit, on the server, call text() on the Request object to obtain the body as a string, and then pass it into qs.parse().
